# Getting error in allure download in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, allure

When downloading allure in jenkins, the following error/stack trace is showing up.

How could I resolve this?

```
Unpacking https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/generic/io/qameta/allure/allure/2.7.0/allure-2.7.0.zip to /var/lib/jenkins/tools/ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation/Allure_2.7.0 on Jenkins
ERROR: Step ‘Allure Report’ aborted due to exception: 
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/generic/io/qameta/allure/allure/2.7.0/allure-2.7.0.zip
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:3000)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong(URLConnection.java:629)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLengthLong(URLConnection.java:501)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(URLConnection.java:485)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentLength(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
    at org.jvnet.robust_http_client.RetryableHttpStream.<init>(RetryableHttpStream.java:90)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/generic/io/qameta/allure/allure/2.7.0/allure-2.7.0.zip
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1944)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1939)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1938)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1508)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    at org.jvnet.robust_http_client.RetryableHttpStream.getStream(RetryableHttpStream.java:98)
    at org.jvnet.robust_http_client.RetryableHttpStream.<init>(RetryableHttpStream.java:91)
    at org.jvnet.robust_http_client.RetryableHttpStream.<init>(RetryableHttpStream.java:74)
    at hudson.ProxyConfiguration.getInputStream(ProxyConfiguration.java:265)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:870)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to install https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/generic/io/qameta/allure/allure/2.7.0/allure-2.7.0.zip to /var/lib/jenkins/tools/ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation/Allure_2.7.0
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:884)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:792)
    at hudson.tools.DownloadFromUrlInstaller.performInstallation(DownloadFromUrlInstaller.java:77)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:72)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:109)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation.forNode(AllureCommandlineInstallation.java:108)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation.forNode(AllureCommandlineInstallation.java:33)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.utils.BuildUtils.setUpTool(BuildUtils.java:39)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.getCommandline(AllureReportPublisher.java:335)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.generateReport(AllureReportPublisher.java:290)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.perform(AllureReportPublisher.java:218)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1823)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

≈

Comment: I reformatted your question to make it more readable.

Answer (score 3):

https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/ is temporary unavailable. As workaround you can configure Jenkins to download Allure from Github releases:

1. Open Jenkins Configuration.
2. Open Jenkins Global Tool Configuration
   (https:///configureTools/)
3. Use the following url in settings below:
   https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/2.7.0/allure-2.7.0.zip

[image: Configuration]